# Unable to detect NVMe M.2 ssd in raspberry pi 4 8gb

Tags: boot, pi-4, power, boot-issues, ubuntu

Is it possible to use an NVMe M.2 as external storage on a Pi4b 8GB?
I have the following PCIe device:  [samsung NVMe PCIe 3.0 SSD 970 Evo plus, 500 gb](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Samsung-MZ-V7S500BW-500GB-Internal-3-500/dp/B07MFBLN7K) +
[external hard drive enclosure](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07ZSG3PVX/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) with a C to A cable and [this power supply](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Miuzei-Raspberry-Power-Supply-Switch/dp/B07XR7YXZX/ref=sr_1_16?dchild=1&keywords=Miuzei&qid=1611945715&s=computers&search-type=ss&sr=1-16)

First I boot from Micro SD and it works fine. But when I plug in NVMe M.2, the Ubuntu 20.10 freezes. The mouse and keyboard do not work well and NVMe M.2 is also not recognized at all.

When I run `lsusb` it identifies PCIe device but `lsblk` can't see it

```
pidev4@pi:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 152d:0583 JMicron Technology Corp. /JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS583Gen 2 to PCIe Gen3x2 Bridge
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046a:0023 Cherry GmbH Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e8f:00a7 GreenAsia Inc.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
pidev4@pi:~$
pidev4@pi:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  48,8M  1 loop /snap/core18/1949
loop1         7:1    0 214,1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/61
loop2         7:2    0  48,8M  1 loop /snap/core18/1888
loop3         7:3    0  62,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop4         7:4    0 197,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/68
loop5         7:5    0  64,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop6         7:6    0  47,3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/476
loop7         7:7    0  48,3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/499
loop8         7:8    0    27M  1 loop /snap/snapd/10709
loop9         7:9    0  26,9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9730
mmcblk0     179:0    0  59,5G  0 disk (micro sd)
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  59,2G  0 part /
```

I want to boot from it but when I take out Micro SD and restart Pi4 I am getting an error message:

> Failed to open device: 'sdcard'.

How can I solve this problem?

Links to any suitable material greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change boot ROM as [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suU09BMMFts)
And you have to have bootable Ubuntu on your USB(SSD), created with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) for example.

Comment: It is not working

Comment: How it is not working? Any error messages?